# Why searching with subjArea and subjCode fetches different results with Scopus Serial Search API?

Tags: python, scopus, pybliometrics

I am trying to retrieve all journals that exist within the a subject area of Scopus, say 'Medicine', using the python package `pybliometrics`.

According to the Scopus search (online), there are 13,477 Journals in this category.

Accessing the [SerialTitle](https://dev.elsevier.com/documentation/SerialTitleAPI.wadl) API of Scopus via `pybliometrics.scopus.SerialSearch()` for category Medicine, the `subjArea='MEDI'` and `subjCode='2700'`. The list of all codes associated with the Scopus subject categories are listed [here](https://api.elsevier.com/content/subject/scopus?httpAccept=text/xml)

I am not able to get more than 5000 journals. But with parameter `subjArea='MEDI'` I am able to retrieve 5000+ documents but not more than 10,000.

I do not understand why searching with `subjArea` and `subjCode` fetches different results for me. Can anyone help me understand why this could be happening?

I am adding my code for both these search queries for better understanding:

```
import pandas as pd
from pybliometrics.scopus import SerialSearch

def search_by_subject_area(subject_area):
    print("Searching journals by subject area....")
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    i = 0
    # limitation of i<10000 is added otherwise raises error of scopus500
    while (i > -1 and i < 10000):
        s = SerialSearch(query={"subj": f"{str(subject_area)}"}, start=f'{i}', refresh=True)
        if s.get_results_size() == 0:
            break
        else:
            i += s.get_results_size()
            df_new = pd.DataFrame(s.results)
            df = pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print(i, " journals obtained!")

def search_by_subject_code(code):
    print("------------------------------------------------\n Searching journals by subject codes....")
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    i = 0
    while (i > -1):
        s = SerialSearch(query={"subjCode": f"{code}"}, start=f'{i}', refresh=True)
        if s.get_results_size() == 0:
            break
        else:
            i += s.get_results_size()
            df_new = pd.DataFrame(s.results)
            df = pd.concat([df, df_new], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print(i, " journals obtained!")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    search_by_subject_area(subject_area = 'MEDI')

    search_by_subject_code('2700')
```

Answer (score 1):

Certain Scopus APIs, including the Serial Search API, are restricted: They do not allow more than 5,000 results.

There are some Search APIs that have pagination active, where they allow you to cycle through a potentially unlimited number of results.

Comment: my query was related to using same SerialSearch API with different parameters. These different parameters are affecting the number of results being fetched.